# jsvideo html5 trouble on iis

Tags: jquery, html, iis, video

I'm having trouble using jsvideo on a IIS server for this project

joewilliegospel .com

For some reason everything works perfectly fine on my local computer but once I uploaded it I ran into the issue of the video not playing.... (when you click on the "Watch Now")....

Not sure what the issue is, but I read it might be from the server so I uploaded this web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogm" mimeType="video/ogg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If anyone can help it would be appreciated, I'm finally learning to use HTML 5 a bit for mobile devices and tablets but I honestly never dealt with IIS before...

Comment: Your [specified video source](http://joewilliegospel.com/vids/Joe-Willie-n-the-Deuteronomaires-Black-Stocking-White-Shoes.mp4) returns a 404

Comment: it shows up on the ftp side, i believe it might be the iis server not recognizing the mp4 filetype...

Comment: Don't think a filetype misconfiguration would result in a 404. But then again I have no clue of IIS....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this had to do with the host: The host had the client on a limited plan for some ODD reason but I switched over to a Linux plan and all has been well. IIS... EUGH.